# Get screen size?

Tags: mobile-website

What is the best way to design screen size, when develop mobile web app? Also how make it compatible all mobile browsers?

Thanks in advance,
sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `width` option based on percent, thats the best way to develop applications and web-pages for mobile phones...

Also, if you are developing for **iPhoneOS** / **Android** based Devices (Or browsers based on **WebKit** framework), check this out, i think you will be interested: http://www.jqtouch.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not all mobile browsers support JavaScript. You can use http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ to get screen size  as well as capabilities of device/phone on server side